# stringstream to array

Tags: c++, arrays, stringstream

could you tell me, why is this wrong?

I have

```
mytype test[2];
stringsstream result;
int value;

for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
   result.str("");
   (some calculating);
   result<< value;
   result>> test[i];
}
```

When I watch to test array - only first - test[0] - has correct value - every other test[1..x] has value 0
why its wrong and not working? in first run in cycle the stringstream set the correct value to array, but later there is only 0?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `result.clear()`ing your stringstream before flushing it with `result.str("")`. This sets it to a state of accepting inputs again after outputting the buffer.

```
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int test[2];
    stringstream result;
    int value;

    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        result.clear();
        result.str("");
        value = i;
        result<< value;
        result>> test[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Without clearing I get `test[0] == 0` and `test[1] == -832551553 /*some random number*/`. With `clear` I get the expected output of `test[0] == 0` and `test[1] == 1`.